# DI & Autowiring vs instantiation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

We are re-architecting a large web application. The application consists of a large number of master tables (around 200-250). We do not use any ORM, but we do have our own bean / POJO framework built on apache commons DynaBean.

We have a thin controller-service-repository framework which can generically handle all master CRUD operations. This framework consists of a Controller Heirarchy - BaseController which implements all the CRUD and routing logic, and controllers derived from the BaseController, which provides the actual repository and view / navigation routes.

```
class BaseController {
     public BaseController(BaseService service, ModelAndView view) {
         this.mav = view;
     }
     // ... Other handler method implementations go here
}
```

Now for the sub-classes

```
class MyService extends BaseService { 
    // All crud methods delegated to / overridden from the base... 
}

class MyModelNView extends ModelAndView { 
    // All routing information & paths specific to this entity
}

@Controller
class MyController extends GenericController {

     // Option 1    
     public MyController() {
        super(new MyService(), new MyModelNView());
     }

     // OR ... Option 2

     // public MyController (MyService service, MyModelNView view) {
     //     super(service, view);
     // }
}
```

Note : MyController will always be associated with MyService and MyModelNView and MyService and MyModelNView will never be associated with a different controller.

**Questions** :

Which of the options, 1 or 2 is the recommended way of instantiating the Service and ModelAndView objects - through a "new" or through autowiring and why ?

I understand that autowiring will allow me to inject a different implementation of MyService in future, if need be, but I am trying to understand if there are any advantages to new instantiation in this specific case where such a possibility is very remote.

Comment: DI makes your code testable. It's also what allows injecting proxies around the object, and those proxies can handle transactions, security, logging, perf measurement, etc. It's really not about injecting other implementations (unless you count proxies and mocks as different implementations).

Comment: (There might be a better duplicate, feel free to change it.)